# Android powerful textview recognize youtube link

Tags: android, youtube, textview

well google has an app which is Keep to taking notes. it has a wonderful feature for example when I am writing note if I pasted a youtube link the app was show that like this screenshoot. how can make it or are there any github. because

`android:autoLink="all"` 
[image]
it was not working good enough

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for link preview libraries like RxUnfurl:

https://www.android-arsenal.com/details/1/4464

Comment: Thansk it looks good but this libraries can not choose link in text. check my screenshoot

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Like this librari, help me https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Android-Link-Preview